# A question about "The Magic Roundabout" cartoon

Tags: movie, the-magic-roundabout

Near the beginning of the *The Magic Roundabout* 2005 cartoon, one of the protagonists, Zebedee, claims that there is a magical diamond hidden in the roundabout which the antagonist Zeebad could use to freeze the sun. Near the end of the film, that is proven wrong. (The diamond was not actually in the roundabout, it was inside a wooden doll called Sam.) So, was Zebedee mistaken about it or was he lying? I can think of arguments either way, but no explanation I can think of makes a lot of sense.

Zebedee could have been lying because he realized the true information about where the diamond is can be used both by the good guys and by the bad guys, and is therefore dangerous. If Zeebad came to know where the diamond was, perhaps Dougal and his friends wouldn't be able to do anything to save the world from Zeebad. The obvious problem with that is why couldn't he simply say "I must not tell you where the third diamond is, as the bad guys must not come to know that?"

Zebedee might have indeed be mistaken at first, thinking that Sam was trapped in the roundabout. The obvious problem with that is that he magically knew where the other magical diamonds were (and explained that to the main protagonist, Dougal, and his friends), so why would this diamond inside Sam be different in that regard? Also, in the middle of the movie, he saw Sam being enchanted to be Zebedee's soldier, so then he definitely couldn't think the diamond was in the roundabout (when, as we learn at the end of the movie, Sam dies when the diamond is taken out of him).

Maybe I am missing something, but this seems like a big incoherence in the plot of the movie.

Comment: This sounds a lot darker than I'd have expected from the film's title; I may have to look this one up!

Comment: @tardigrade What do you mean by "I may have to look this one up!"?